# Hive: Difference between NULL col_name and NULL as col_name in table DDL

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can someone please explain me the difference between "NULL col_name" and "NULL as col_name" in hive table DDL. Examples below:

CREATE TABLE table_null AS
  SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4 FROM(
    'col1' as c1,
    'col2' as c2,
     NULL as c3,
     NULL c4 ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive and MySQL, the `select` statement having `<value/col_name> as <col_alias>` and `<value/col_name> <col_alias>` gives the same output. `as` is optional keyword.

Below examples may clarify better:

- Hive query

[image]

- MySQL query

[image]

In other databases also it may follow the same rule.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same.  They can be tested this way:

```
select *
from (
    select NULL col1, NULL as col2
    from test_nulls ) tabl
where col1 is NULL and col2 is NULL;
```